# Django Reverse for function with arguments '()' and keyword arguments {'status': 'Done'} not found

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect to another from a Django view, like so

```
url = reverse("enterOTP",args=(),  kwargs={"status": status})

def enterOTP(request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = OTP()
        return render(request,"enterotp.html", {"form":form, "status":status})
```

And this is my URLconf

```
url(r'enterotp/(?P<status>[-\w]+)/$', 'FlowSimulator.views.enterOTP', name = "enterOTP")
```

I keep getting the NoReverseMatch error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What file is that URL in? Is it included from another file, via a namespace?

Comment: Why is your call to `reverse` at the module's top-level, where does `status` come from (module global ???) and what is `status` value ?

Answer (score 0):

Your URLconf might not have been loaded at the time you try to reverse the URL. Try [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead

Comment: Still getting this : Reverse for 'enterOTP' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: That is a different error message. Are you passing `status`?

Comment: Also, is this from your top level urls.py or is it included in another urls.py with a namespace?

Comment: Top level. I believe that the problem is probably in the regex in the URLconf